# Keep whitespace and comment in ANTLR4

Tags: antlr4

When I run InsertSerialID.java or ExtractInterfaceTool.java in ANTLR4 tour source pack( https://pragprog.com/titles/tpantlr2/source_code ), I found all the white-space and comments are not included in the output. So the output source code cannot be compiled or readable. How to keep them?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found redirect to an extra channel will keep them in the `Token`, instead of use `skip`

```
WS  :  [ \t\r\n\u000C]+  -> channel(2) // -> skip
    ;

COMMENT
    :   '/*' .*? '*/'  -> channel(2) // -> skip
    ;

LINE_COMMENT
    :   '//' ~[\r\n]* -> channel(2) // -> skip
    ;
```

They saved in `ParserRuleContext.getSourceInterval()` as `Interval`, although I don't know how to map `Interval` to thier gramma type.